# Ember - Pass html element as parameter from ember template to component on click action

Tags: ember.js

How can we pass element object in handlebar's onclick action. I tried passing `this` but that doesn't worked.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick={{action "menuClickEvent" this}}>Menu Item</a>
```

**Component.js**

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    menuClickEvent: function(element) {          
      // need element <a> to do jquery operation
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass it. Element is accessible as an event `target` property.

```
<a onclick={{action "menuClickEvent"}}>Menu Item</a>
```

By passing `this` you are passing current `component`. So just remove this parameter from your code. You can remove this `javascript:void(0)` 90' thing. The href parameter is optional in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#placeholder-hyperlink), so you can remove it as well.

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    menuClickEvent: function(e) {          
      console.log(e.target); // here you go with the `a` element for your black ops
    }
  }
});
```

You may think about a better name than `menuClickEvent`.

Comment: Thanks @Wojciech Bednarski. It worked !!! I am using a different name for that click event in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general `click` method ember.js provides:

```
<a>Menu Item</a>
```

**component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  click(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
});
```

However, I often think you should not work on DOM elements directly in ember.js. I think you can solve your original problem in a different and better way, so you don't need to access the underlying DOM element directly.